# Django template : use a filter result as an argument to a second filter

Tags: python, django, django-template-filters

What I'd like to achieve is to make a calculation in Django template, In plain maths that would be :

```
section_angle = base_angle + ( sections_length / current_iteration_counter_over_sections)
```

When trying to translate it in Django template, I think that could be something like :

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {% with base_angle|add:sections|length|divides:forloop.counter0 as section_angle %}
```

With a custom *divides* filter looking like

```
def divides(value, param):
    return float(param)/float(value)
```

I'm a bit confused about how to arrange it, the orders of filters and arguments I should use. With the example showed here, it leads to an error : *Caught ValueError while rendering: could not convert string to float:*

Bonus question : I tried to add parenthesis to clarify but the template engine seems to not like it.

Comment: shouldn't `sections|length` be `sections_length`?

Comment: While you might be able to achieve this, but to keep it readable, I would just create a templatetag to achieve the same.

Comment: why not just make a template tag to do the entire calculation?

Comment: @J0HN it's called *sections_length* in the "math" example to make it clearer, but in code I have to use the length filter

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony & karthikr : I guess this is the only reasonable thing to do :)

Comment: I think this might be the source of error. Filters applied one after another, so your construct reads as `((base_angle|add:sections)|length)`, while you meant `base_angle|add:(sections|length)`. But I'm not sure :). In short, you are trying to manipulate it in a clever way, but it works not entirely as you think. So better do it some other way.

Comment: @challet advice: The view layer shouldn't do that things, use template tags only for view/design issues. the calculation you are trying to do should be done in the model/controller level.

Comment: @YardenST well, that could be seen as design issues, since the goal is to make an SVG view (can be the subject of my next question ^^) of the "sections". the variable manipulations I'm trying to achieve is more translating list items into angled elements than to make hard calculations. But yes, that wouldn't hurt to use a "listToAngle" model method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do that. The Django template system is not the place to put such a logic. 
Read the [Philosophy comments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/#the-django-template-language) about templates in the Django official website:

> If you have a background in programming, or if you’re used to
>   languages which mix programming code directly into HTML, you’ll want
>   to bear in mind that the Django template system is not simply Python
>   embedded into HTML. This is by design: the template system is meant to
>   express presentation, not program logic.

I think the Timmy's comment is right, put the entire logic in a custom filter.